# Browser not automatically decompressing gz file

Tags: php, css, header, gzip

I have the same website with the same css file being gzipped and served on two separate servers.  Viewing the site on one server, the browser properly decompresses it, and uses the styling.  But on the other, the browser does not decompress the file.  I thought perhaps this is something to do with the headers, but all the resources I've found seem to think the Content-Type and Content-Encoding are the only two headers that matter for decompressing gzip, and those are the same on both servers.  Is there another response header that is incorrect?

The working response headers for the .css.gz file:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: public, max-age=604800, must-revalidate
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Type: text/css
Age: 353722
Date: Tue, 07 Apr 2015 21:44:23 GMT
Last-Modified: Tue, 29 Oct 2013 17:44:18 GMT
Expires: Fri, 10 Apr 2015 19:29:01 GMT
Content-Length: 33130
Connection: keep-alive
```

The response headers for the .css.gz file that don't seem to work:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 08 Apr 2015 15:14:11 GMT
Content-Type: text/css
Last-Modified: Tue, 07 Apr 2015 22:42:25 GMT
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: close
Content-Encoding: gzip
```

Comment: And you're doing what exactly, you're serving a `.css.gz` file from disk? Is it possible that your second server is additionally gzipping the response, so you're getting a two-layer gzip of which only the outer layer is being decompressed?

Comment: Yes.  The above response is the headers for the .css.gz file, not the page.  I tried diffing the responses, and they're identical.